# Why for creation of delay the static refrence to Thread.sleep is preferred not this.sleep?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, delay

In the code below the compiler suggested me to use Thread.sleep (the static reference ) not this.sleep, why is that?

```
public class CThreadUsingThread extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Thread running:"+i);

            try {
                // Why Thread.sleep(Math.round(Math.random()*1000)); is preferred?
                this.sleep(Math.round(Math.random()*1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("Thread interrupted!");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] orgs){
        CThreadUsingThread thread  = new CThreadUsingThread();
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

[image: Also attached the image to make it more visible]

Comment: Because you aren't supposed to invoke static methods on an instance variable, it's going to use the solitary definition anyway.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(long)` is a `static` method. The instance doesn't matter.

Comment: My guess is clarity, so when someone goes back to look at this code  there is 0 confusion.

Comment: You really shouldn't be extending `Thread` anyway.

Comment: @BrianRoach, why? and you mean implementing runnabl would be a better choice?

Comment: Correct; see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread

Comment: @Cgraphics Yes.  Generally speaking you're not actually adding any functionality to the Thread class and given the fact it can only be run once, it's generally encouraged to use Runnable instead.

Comment: extending Thread is a simple way to write really confusing code in Java.  If you look at Java Puzzlers book a number of the confusing puzzles all use `extends Thread`

Answer (score 6):

Your code is misleading, basically. It *looks* like you're referring to a specific thread, when *actually* it's just calling the static `Thread.sleep` method which *always* refers to the currently executing thread.

In this particular case it's not *hugely* misleading, but it's still not nice. Consider this rather worse case though:

```
CThreadUsingThread thread  = new CThreadUsingThread();
thread.start();
thread.sleep(1000);
```

Which thread does it *look* like that will send to sleep? And which thread is it *actually* going to send to sleep?

As an aside, I'd also:

- Avoid the `C` prefix for classes; `CThreadUsingThread` isn't a conventional Java name
- Prefer creating a `Runnable` and passing that to the `Thread` constructor, rather than subclassing `Thread` directly. It's a cleaner separation of code which is explicitly about threading and code which is just giving the thread some code to run.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.sleep` is a `static` method.  Java allows you to access a static method with a reference variable, but from the syntax it's not clear that it's a call to a static method.

It's always clearer to call a static method from the class name instead of from a reference variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because Thread.Sleep is static, you are calling a static method with your Thread instance.  It is not necessary to do so.

Also, it's not a good idea to extend Thread.  Wrapping thread inside of a custom class is fine.

Comment: `Wrapping thread inside of a custom class is fine` what you mean with this? Creating a Runnable instance and setting to the thread?